XSLT - Comparing 2 documents for matching parent and child elements
If I have the following two XML docs:
untranslated file:
 <body>
     <trans-unit id="Id a" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>original a</source>
     </trans-unit>
     <trans-unit id="Id b" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>original b</source>
     </trans-unit>
     <trans-unit id="Id c" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>original c</source>
     </trans-unit>
 </body>

translated file:
 <body>
     <trans-unit id="Id a" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>original a</source>
     </trans-unit>
     <trans-unit id="Id b" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>translated b</source>
     </trans-unit>
 </body>

I want to be able to output only the items where the source is different between the two. In this case the trans-unit 'Id a' is untranslated (the source is the same between both docs) so I want to exclude it. I only want to see the trans-unit 'Id b' from the second translated file because the source element contents is different.
Also, I cannot guarantee that both trans-units are in each file, as per 'Id c'.
Final output document:
 <body>
     <trans-unit id="Id b" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>translated b</source>
     </trans-unit>
 </body>

I don't have much experience with XSL, I am assuming this will involve holding one of the document's contents in a variable and performing tests against it but I could be incorrect
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="mytranslatedfile" select="document('translatedfile.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="translated" select="$mytranslatedfile/trans-unit/id" />

<xsl:template match="trans-unit/source">
     <xsl:choose>

<!----- if the id is the same between the documents ----->

     <xsl:when test="$translated[ancestor::trans-unit[1]/@id]">

<!----- add an additional test here to compare the source? unsure how to do this ----->

<!----- I want to output the trans-unit element and child source element here ----->
     <P> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </P>

     </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

With XSLT 3 and keys (second document is inlined for self containedness of example but could be a <xsl:param name="translation" select="doc('translations.xml')"/> instead:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:key name="translated" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="source" match="trans-unit" composite="yes" use="@id, source"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="main" select="/"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="trans-unit/key('translated', @id, $translation)[not(key('source', (@id, source), $main))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="translation">
     <body>
         <trans-unit id="Id a" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                    <source>original a</source>
         </trans-unit>
         <trans-unit id="Id b" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                    <source>translated b</source>
         </trans-unit>
     </body>    
  </xsl:param>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

Example fiddle is here.

In XSLT 2.0 or higher, you could do simply:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="translatedfile" select="document('translatedfile.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="trans-unit">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', @id, $translatedfile)[source != current()/source]"/>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but this should work:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="translatedfile" select="document('translatedfile.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="trans-unit">
            <xsl:variable name="translation" select="$translatedfile/body/trans-unit[@id = current()/@id]" />
            <xsl:if test="source != $translation/source">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$translation"/>
            </xsl:if>   
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

This is assuming the untranslated file is the XML input to the XSL transformation.
